# Dense sets with respect to given metrics and their restrictions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and consider two  subsets $Y \subset Z \subset X$.

Assume $Y$ is dense in $X$ with respect to $d$. Can we then automatically conclude that $Y$ is also a dense subset of the subspace $(Z, d_{Z\times Z})$, where  $d_{Z\times Z}(a,b)=d(a,b)$, $a,b \in Z$, denotes the usual metric restriction?

Which is the actual difference between the closures of $Y$ in $(X,d)$ and $(Z, d_{Z\times Z})$, respectively?

I was starting by considering the easy example of 
$$
X=[0,1], \, Z=(0,1), \, Y=(0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}
$$
with $d$ denoting the Euclidean metric. This  setting complies with the above assumption. Herein, I guess the closure of $Y$ in $(Z, d_{Z\times Z})$ is trivially $Z$, so $Y$ is also dense in this subspace. Such closure differs from that in $X$ by the two points $\{0,1\}$, the only ones which are not allowed as limit points in $Z$.

Is this true in general, i.e. the closure of $Y$ in $(Z, d_{Z\times Z})$ is trivially $\overline{Y}\cap Z$ (thus the answer to my initial question is positive)? Or am I missing something stupid?

Comment: Notation: $\overline{Y}$ is the $d$-closure of $Y$ in $X$.

Comment: If $T$ is a topology on a set $X$ and $Y\subset X$ then the subpace topology on $Y$ is $T_Y=\{t\cap Y: t\in T\}.$ Now $T$ is generated by a metric $d$ iff the set $B$ of open  $d$-balls in $X$ is a base (basis) for $T.$ Then $C= \{b\cap Y:b\in B\}$ is a base for $T_Y...$ An often overlooked point is that  the set $B_Y$ of open $d$-balls in the set $Y$ may be a proper subset of $ C.$ But $C$ and $B_Y$ $ do$ generate the same topology.  E.g. $X=\Bbb R$ with $d(u,v)=|u-v|$ and $Y=X\setminus \{0\}.$ Then $ (-1,0)\cup  (0,1)\in C$ \ $B_Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true in general that the closure of $Y$ in $Z$ is the intersection if the closure of $Y$ in $X$ with $Z$. In fact, if $z\in Z$ belongs to the closure of $Y$ in $Z$, then it follows from the definition of closure that $z$ belongs to the closure of $Y$ in $X$. On the other hand, if $z$ belongs to the closure of $Y$ in $X$ and if it turns out that $z\in Z$, then (again, by the definition of closure) $z$ belongs to the closure of $Y$ in $Z$.

Comment: +1. My edit was for a typo: "closeure".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you.